# Azure API Management With OpenAPI (FunctionApps) getting 401

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, swashbuckle

My requirements are to host APIs, with Function Apps as backend. I also want the documentation for those APIs (automatically generated through function-App code (so I don't have to write documentation on Api-management))

I have setup API management to import APIs from swagger file (OpenAPI) that is exposed through a URL in my FunctionApp.

The APIs look fine and I can see it in Developer-Portal on API-Management. But when I actually make the call, it fails with 401.

I am guessing the token sent to FunctionApp is wrong or missing when API-Management sends the request.

My question how/where to configure that token that're configured on function app.

Secondly, is this the right approach? I am using Swagger nugget to configure/generate documentation of APIs on functionApp and import that swagger-json into api-management (OpenAPI option), or is there a better way to expose documentation of functionapp-apis through API-Management.

P.S. If I import the APIs using FunctionApps option, everything works fine but I dont get the documentation I want.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

**For swagger**:
Consider using Swashbuckle - see this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). NSwag is an alternative.

**For Functions**:
Function Apps can either be accessed anonymously or require a key. There are multiple levels of keys ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts)). Keys for the App are located in the App Keys blade [image: App keys] (note: Microsoft are tweaking the UI, so this is subject to change).

Keys at the individual Function can be found in the Function's Function Keys blade.

If the Function requires a key it must be passed with the request.

**For APIM:**
Each API in APIM must be part of one or more Products. Products contain the APIs. The APIs contain endpoints/operations. Access to products is controlled by [subscription keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions). The APIs and operations can also decide whether a subscription is required. If a subscription key is required it must be passed with request.

APIM support policies at global (all APIs), API (all operations) and individual APIs. These policies, which could involve checking for prerequisites (JWT bearer tokens for example), can return customer response codes like 401. Check you are providing the necessary prerequisites.

In APIM when adding a new API, you have the option of choosing a Function App and picking from existing Azure Functions. It should automatically sets up the Function auth (you don't have to handle passing keys yourself).